# Can I open a file as root by just using the right click menu

Tags: nautilus, sudo, context-menu, gksudo, nautilus-actions

Opening file as root is possible with ***sudo***. But, how to right click a file and make it ***run as root*** ?

I am using nautilus.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need the admin extension

```
$ apt-cache search nautilus | grep admin
nautilus-admin - Extension for Nautilus to do administrative operations
```

Install it with `sudo apt-get install nautilus-admin`

Comment: Does this works for Raspberry PI ? I had installed but there's no something like `run as root` in context menu.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the solution from [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/?s=root%2Fadministrator), and it works fine (running 14.04/nautilus).

[image]

To *not* post a link-only answer:

1. install `gksu`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gksu
   ```
2. Navigate to `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts`
3. Create and open an empty file, name it `open-as-administrator`, paste the script below:

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash
   #
   # this code will determine exactly the path and the type of object,
   # then it will decide use gedit or nautilus to open it by ROOT permission
   #
   # Determine the path
   if [ -e -n $1 ]; then
   obj="$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS"
   else
   base="`echo $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI | cut -d'/' -f3- | sed 's/%20/ /g'`"
   obj="$base/${1##*/}"
   fi
   # Determine the type and run as ROOT
   if [ -f "$obj" ]; then
   gksu gedit "$obj"
   elif [ -d "$obj" ]; then
   gksu nautilus "$obj"
   fi

   exit 0
   ```
4. Make the script executable
5. Either log out and back in, or run:

   ```
   nautilus -q
   ```

***AGAIN: the script is not mine!*** found it on http://ubuntuhandbook.org

Comment: Use `sudo apt-get install nautilus-admin` method instead of making your own system scripts. Then you will get updates when/id needed.

Comment: @SorenA what do you suggest, never post your own alternative if another solution exists? Furthermore, the *concept* of this answer could be usefull to someone to perform other actions on the file, not available in existing nautilus actions.

Comment: What I mean is never to propose a "manual" unsupported solution, when you know that a working supported one exists. As for the concept part you could have a point, but I fear that it will confuse more ppl than it will help.

Comment: @SorenA there could be a million reasons to use a "home-made" alternative. Flexibility is one; functionality can easily be changed or fine tuned. Even only for that reason, the answer is useful. Confuse? then don't play around with it if you don't understand.