# Add right-click option to "run as root"

Tags: ubuntu-mate, caja

So far, I can find sufficient answers telling how to add a "run as root" to right click menu in `nautilus`. However, with `caja`, as expected, doesn't work to use the [same technique as with nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/703530/can-i-open-a-file-as-root-by-just-using-the-right-click-menu)

Comment: In caja, by default, I have "Run as administrator" when I right click on a file, maybe it's not activated for you, in caja, click on Edit -> preferences and click on Extensions tab, see if anything's disabled.

Comment: And I'm using nemo as my default file manager, and I have an option called "Open as root" when I right click on an empty space inside any directory which prompts to open nemo as root, and any program I run from there will be run as root.

Comment: @Shayan Found it. It was an unchecked gksu. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntumate 16.04 running on Raspberry Pi:  There is no option to "run as root".  However, inputing "gksu caja" in the terminal does work to open a folder as root.